# Google Analytics view with no filters shows fewer real-time visitors than a view with filters

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, real-time

I just finished the Google Analytics courses, and the company I work for wants me to be in charge of supervising our clients' reports, since no one's doing it at the time.

We have had the accounts for a while, and some views already have some filters and goals applied. I wanted to start from zero, configuring views the way I learned in the courses, so I created completely new views.
The problem is this:

- I created a view and added a goal. There was already one view in this account, with 4 exclusion filters and some goals. The goal I added for my view is just like one in the other view.
- I went to the real time reports of both views and my view was showing fewer visitors than the other one.

How is this possible? Shouldn't it be the other way since my view doesn't even have any filters?

Also, I copied the view that already existed, then went to the real time report of this copy and it was showing zero active users. So, yeah, I'm confused.

Comment: What were the filters excluding?

Answer (score 1):

when you implement a filter it will block fake traffic from bots. In order to determine that the traffic is legit check the bounce rate and the source of the traffic

usually in the referral area the site list will appear like this:

```
7makemoneyonline.com
ilovevitaly.com
345bcoznet.com
8782342.com
paydayloan.com
```

and the bounce rate are high(100%) with 0 time spent on your website.

for real-time it traffic it may vary from industry/niche so if your business niche is really competitive so expect more real-time views every hour. And usually it will take 24 hours for analytics data to reflect if you want to look at the traffic.